# telethon accounts get banned despite proxy

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a simple code with which I work with accounts:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.photos import DeletePhotosRequest
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient


def decor(func):
    async def wrapper(account, proxy, *args, **kwargs):
        proxy = {
            'proxy_type': ProxyType.SOCKS5,
            'addr': proxy.host,
            'port': proxy.port,
            'username': proxy.login,
            'password': proxy.password
        }
        client = TelegramClient(f'site/mail_sessions/{account}', API_ID, API_HASH, proxy=proxy, connection_retries=0, timeout=3)
        try:
            await client.connect()
        except ConnectionError as ex:
            return {'success': False, 'has_ban': False, 'proxy_issue': True, 'result': str(ex)}
        try:
            result = await func(client, *args, **kwargs)
        except rpcerrorlist.UserDeactivatedBanError as ex:
            return {'success': False, 'has_ban': True, 'proxy_issue': False, 'result': str(ex)}
        except Exception as ex:
            return {'success': False, 'result': str(ex), 'has_ban': False, 'proxy_issue': False}
        else:
            return {'success': True, 'result': result, 'has_ban': False, 'proxy_issue': False}
        finally:
            await client.disconnect()
    return wrapper

@decor
async def delete_photos(client):
    res = []
    photos = await client.get_profile_photos('me')
    for photo in photos:
        el = await client(DeletePhotosRequest(id=[InputPhoto(id=photo.id, access_hash=photo.access_hash, file_reference=photo.file_reference)]))
        res.append(el)
    return res
```

Using the `delete_photos` function, I check the health of accounts a couple of times a day
I use individual ipv4 proxies, I buy accounts in different places. But despite this, all accounts get ban after a few days with different errors:

- The user has been deleted/deactivated
- The key is not registered in the system
- The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions

telethon v: 1.28.5

The question is, what could I write wrong in the code that accounts get ban so quickly. I do not send messages from them, I only check them with the `delete_photos` function

Comment: Read [tos](https://core.telegram.org/api/terms), if you break them, we can't/won't/shouldn't help you here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comment in the original question, when you develop an application using Telegram's API, you are bound to their terms of service.

Ultimately, Telegram decides how, why and when to ban certain actions, legitimate or not.

https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/824 contains more information, but the TL;DR is, it's on them, not much Telethon can do, which has unfortunately been abused by a lot of spammers, so Telegram is more than glad to jump the gun.